# Set cookie from subdomain to root domain and all subdomains

Tags: express, cookies

I set a cookie by making a request from `example.io` to `api.example.io/set_cookie`. The cookie looks like so:

```
jwt=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIyMjdlNTU5MC0zODJkLTExZWEtOTA0ZC05NzljOTIyNmZiZmQiLCJpYXQiOjE1NzkxNTc3MDkzNDR9.Sz-_8M4M1te82Z-PuG9H8MUNlLGPUGdGLfQ_-YuL9xA; Domain=example.io; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 15 Jan 2021 06:55:09 GMT; HttpOnly
```

I specify the domain to be `example.io`. So, I expect the browser to send this cookie to any subsequent requests to `api.example.io` and `example.io`. However, this does not happen. I think I'm following the advice in [Share cookie between subdomain and domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain).

Comment: How do you know it's not being saved in Chrome?  It is httpOnly so it won't be available to Javascript in a web page.

Comment: I do not see any cookies in the storage section of application tab of developers tool in chrome. Regardless, I do not care if javascript reads it. All I care about is the cookie should be sent to subsequent request to api.example.io