# Cookie set on root domain not available to subdomain - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: express, cookies, setcookie, csrf-token

Client hosted on `subdomain.example.com` makes api call to `example.com` to fetch a cookie. The response has a `Set-cookie` header and I see the cookie as being returned alright:

[image]

However, I don't see the cookie saved in the Browser (Chrome, Firefox, Edge) and, as a result, is not sent as a header in subsquent API requests:

[image]

`Set-cookie` `domain` attribute is set to `.example.com`, but as I read in MDN I think the trailing dot gets ignored.

The cookie in question, by the way, is the csrf token secret set by the `csurf` library.

What am I doing wrong? I have been troubleshooting for 3 evenings now, I don't have a clue yet. seems to be same question as [0] but that one is unanswered. Thanks!

[0] [Set cookie from subdomain to root domain and all subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59764682/set-cookie-from-subdomain-to-root-domain-and-all-subdomains)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly I didn't have a good enough understanding of cors - [0] put me on the right track. It was due to not doing doing the AJAX request with `withCredentials` client side and `credentials: true` because I am setting an origin since server in `example.com` in not the same as `subdomain.example.com`. Hope it is helpful

[0] https://stackoverflow.com/a/60142012/3630417